# Why the below mentioned code works only for a particular set of inputs?

Tags: c++, depth-first-search

```
//DFS of connected and disconnected graphs

#include <iostream>
#include <vector>

using namespace std;

class Graph {
    int V;
    vector<int> *adj;
    void DFSutil(int v, bool visited[]);
public: 
    Graph(int V);
    void addEdge(int v, int w);
    void DFS();
    //void DFS(int v); for connected
};

Graph::Graph(int V) {
    this->V = V;
    adj = new vector<int>[V];
}

void Graph::addEdge(int v, int w) {
    adj[v].push_back(w);
}

void Graph::DFSutil(int v, bool visited[]) {
    visited[v] = true;
    cout << v << " ";

    vector<int>::iterator i;
    for (i=adj[v].begin(); i!= adj[v].end(); ++i)
        if(!visited[*i]) 
            DFSutil(*i,visited);
}

void Graph::DFS() {
    bool* visited = new bool[V];
    for (int i=0; i<V; ++i) {
        visited[i] = false;
    }

    for (int i=0; i<V; ++i) {
        if (visited[i] == false)
            DFSutil(i, visited);
    }

    // simply DFSutil(v,visited) if you are sure every vertex is reachable from any vertex, i.e., graph is connected

}

int main()
{
    // Create a graph given in the above diagram
    int N, E, N1, N2;
    cin >> N >> E;
    Graph g(N);
    while(E--) {
        cin >> N1 >> N2;
        cout << N1 << " " << N2 <<" added" << endl;
        g.addEdge(N1, N2);
    }

    cout << "Following is Depth First Traversal\n";
    g.DFS();
    //g.DFS(2) for connected

    return 0;
}
```

The above is a simple implementation for DFS which should work well for connected and disconnected graphs including trees. 
For the input (connected graph) -

```
4 6
0 1
0 2
1 2
2 0 
2 3
3 3
```

It shows success, but for input (tree) -

```
3 2
1 2
2 3
```

It shows runtime error on Ideone.

Am I missing something here?

Comment: if someone wants to downvote, they better leave a comment as to why they did so and probably show me a way out too if they think it is too trivial.

Comment: Try debugging your code

Comment: Simple debugging questions aren't a good fit for SO because they are very unlikely to be of use to future readers. You have a very specific problem and fixing it won't help anyone else.

Comment: I thought I was missing something traversal related. I am amazed why I was not able to debug.

Answer (score 0):

The problem is not in your code, but in your sample:

```
3 2
1 2
2 3
```

Here you mean a graph with 3 vertices (numbered from 0 to 2 as it's obvious from your first example and from your code). But the edges added connect vertices `1 and 2` and `2 and 3`. There's not an error when you add an edge from `2` to `3` (yes, that's a logic error, consider adding an assertion here, but the crash does not happen since this edge is added to the adjacency vector of vertex 2). But in DFS, you see this edge when launched from the vertex 2, and try to check whether or not the vertex 3 was visited, accessing the element out of the array bounds, which is UB.

This may be seen in 2 minutes in debugger, why don't you debug your code prior to posting questions?